# Meta analysis of generic inverse variance

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, mortality

I'm doing a a meta analysis on the mortality of heart failure patients and I'm using hazard ratios reported in the studies for the meta-analysis using REVMAN software.

All of the hazard ratios and confidence interval of the studies are entered without a problem, except for only one study which the program can't accepts the hazard ratio and its confidence interval like in the attached photo , the reported value in the paper is hazard ratio 0.31 95% CI 0.005-.74 p value = 0.0016

[image]

Comment: The figures you quote in your text do not agree with what you typed in to the software. Which are correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reported value in the paper might not be correct.

For linear regressions, we can assume that the $\hat{\beta}$s have an approximately normal distribution. Then your 95% confidence interval can be estimated by the formula:

$$\hat{\beta}\pm1.96SE$$, since the paper reported the HR and 95% CI, you can calculate the $\hat{\beta}$ and $SE$ from the Hazard ratio and the 95% confidence interval either to use the upper limit or the lower limit and you should get a very close value of SE.

Let's do an upper limit first

$$\log(0.31)+1.96SE=\log(0.74)\\\Rightarrow 1.96SE=\log(\frac{0.74}{0.31})\\\Rightarrow SE=0.4439713$$

Let's do a lower limit

$$\log(0.31)-1.96SE=\log(0.005)\\\Rightarrow 1.96SE=\log(\frac{0.31}{0.005})\\\Rightarrow SE=2.105681$$

In theory, we should get exactly the same SE from the two equations (in reality there can be a little difference due to rounding). However, the SE is quite different from the two calculations.

Therefore, my conclusion is that the reported value in the paper might not be correct. You may ask the authors to clarify it.

Comment: The OP has inconsistent values in the text and the screenshot.